# How can audio data be abstracted for comparison purposes?

Tags: audio, abstraction

I am working on a project involving machine learning and data comparison.

For the purpose of this project, I am feeding abstracted video data to a neuronal network.

Now, abstracting image data is quite simple. I can take still-frames at certain points in the video, scale them down into 5 by 5 pixels (or any other manageable resolution) and get the pixel values for analysis.

The resulting data gives a unique, small and somewhat data-rich sample (even 5 samples of 5x5 px are enough to distinguish a drama from a nature documentary, etc).

However, I am stuck on the audio part. Since audio consists of samples and each sample by itself has no inherent meaning, I can't find a way to abstract audio down into processable blocks.

Are there common techniques for this process? If not, what metrics can audio data be quantified and abstracted in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The process you require is *audio feature extraction*.   A large number of feature detection algorithms exist, usually specialising in signals that are music or speech.
For music, chromacity, rhythm, harmonic distribution are all features you might extract - along with many more.
Typically, audio feature extraction algorithms work at a fairly macro level - that is to say thousands of samples at a time.

A good place to get started is [Sonic visualiser](http://www.sonicvisualiser.org) which is a plug-in host for audio visualisation algorithms - many of which are feature extractors.

[YAAFE](http://yaafe.sourceforge.net) may also have some useful stuff in it.